# how to create a mpd file using dashencoder

Tags: mpd

I have a video file name `"test.mp4"`, this file contains the video + audio. and I want make different MPD's by using `"DashEncoder.config"` file. Can any one tell me that what are the changes required to to change the in the "DashEncoder.config"?

I made MPD's already but there is no voice in generated MPD's. :(

please help

Comment: I don't have any domain knowledge here, but as written I feel like there isn't enough information here to fully help you. It would be useful to tell us what exactly you've tried and/or why you think it may not be working.

Comment: If you don't have domain knowledge then how will you understand my work? :) please see the below link.  http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/?p=291